# internal 500 server Post error rails + angular +ajax id error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

so my rails log prints the following when doing a post request from the frontend with ajax

```
 MedicalService Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "medical_services".* FROM "medical_services" WHERE "medical_services"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7.2ms

 NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
 app/controllers/provider_medical_services_controller.rb:50:in `create_service_with_cpt'
```

which is weird because all I'm doing is finding the id from that table with this action from the controller

```
def create_service_with_cpt
 ms = MedicalService.find_by_id(params[:id])
 puts ms.inspect

 pms = ProviderMedicalService.new
 pms.medical_service_id = ms.id
 pms.provider_id = current_provider.id
 pms.cash_price = params[:cash_price]
 pms.average_price = params[:average_price]
 pms.description = params[:description]
 pms.save
 render json: pms
end
```

but i have change the find by id to this

```
 ms = MedicalService.find_by_id(params[:id].to_i)
```

my rails console reports a different error

```
MedicalService Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "medical_services".* FROM "medical_services" WHERE "medical_services"."id" = 0 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8.3ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/provider_medical_services_controller.rb:50:in `create_service_with_cpt'
```

i checked in my rails console and there exists a medical id. But i have no idea why the action is failing?

the model for MedicalService

```
class MedicalService < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :service, :description, :specialty_id, :approved

  has_many :provider_medical_services
  has_many :providers, through: :provider_medical_services

  has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

the post request after hitting the submit button

```
 Started POST "/api/provider_medical_services/existing" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-17 14:39:35 -0700
 Processing by ProviderMedicalServicesController#create_service_with_cpt as JSON
 Parameters: {"async_selected_treatment"=>{"approved"=>true, "created_at"=>"2014-07-17T08:29:41Z", "description"=>"Regular Check up", "id"=>1, "service"=>"92113", "specialty_id"=>nil, "standard"=>nil, "updated_at"=>"2014-07-17T08:29:41Z"}, "average_price"=>300, "cash_price"=>200, "description"=>"Regular Check up", "service"=>"92113", "provider_medical_service"=>{"cash_price"=>200, "average_price"=>300}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `.find_by_id(params[:id].to_i)` excess use `.find(params[:id])` instead.
- Looks like `params[:id]` always `nil`, this first log `"id" IS NULL LIMIT 1` this second `"id" = 0 LIMIT 1`. `nil.to_i` return `0`

I think problem then you try call `create_service_with_cpt` somewhere in frontend.

Maybe right `id` this `params["async_selected_treatment"]["id"]`?